# .htaccess redirection for wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wildcard-subdomain

i have a domain example.com and created a wildcard subdomain to point it to the DOC root

I want it so anyone can use `name.example.com` and then have it add their affiliate ID to the end `name.example.com/a/5`

I have created the following .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.name.example.com/a/1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

this is redirecting correctly to `www.name.example.com/a/1/`  but I need it as `name.example.com/a/1/`

when I remove the www from the .htaccess rule it is making a redirect loop

webserver is apache

Comment: Is `a` in the uri `/a/1` a fixed path?

Comment: yes "a" in the url   will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the destination you are redirecting to.

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!a).*)$ http://name.example.com/a/1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Or this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://name.example.com/a/1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Clear your browser cache or use a diffrent browser to test this.

Comment: the first rule is redirecting to http://name.example.com/a/1/index.php but getting the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" The second rule is not making any changes in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

let me first put your code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.name.example.com/a/1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The condition will match the sub domain `name.example.com/whatever` without `wwww` so , it will work fine because you redirect to `www.name.example.com/whatever` ,but if you remove `www` from substitution , it means you redirect `name.example.com/whatever` to `name.example.com/a/1/whatever` the redirect it again because there is no restriction like if not match directory `/a/` do this rule and that why looping happened.

So , you should redirect both the exclude `/a/` directory from `URI` but by saying , URI not containing `/a/` like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?name\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !/a/   http://name.example.com/a%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note :** clear browser cache then test it .

Comment: I have used that code it is redirecting to "http://toddtest.alor.com/a/1/index.php" 

But getting a message "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."